# How to send a pdf file for ajax response using flask?

Tags: ajax, flask, pdf

I am trying to display a pdf file in the browser without downloading it for the user. So currently I have a flask function that can generate a pdf file using FPDF module and I need it to be displayed to the user in a new tab.

The current flask function is

```
@app.route('/pdf/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_pdf():
    if not session.get('email'):
        return redirect(url_for('login_page'))
    email = session.get('email')
    pdf = FPDF('P', 'mm', "A4")
    pdf.add_page()
    .... pdf making ...
    pdf.output(f"pdf/mypdf.pdf")
    return send_file(f"pdf/mypdf.pdf",
                     mimetype='application/pdf',
                     attachment_filename=f"My file.pdf",
                     as_attachment=True,
                     cache_timeout=-1)
```

I call the ajax function as

```
$("#viewFile").on("click",function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: "{{url_for('create_pdf')}}",
      type: "get",
      data: {text: mytext},
      success: function(response) {
        window.open(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        alert("Error: Failed to save notes.");
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the parameter `as_attachment` you can specify whether the browser should save the file or offer it for display. If the value is set to `False`, the file should be displayed. (See [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.send_file))

The following example also shows you how you can deliver the pdf document without saving it temporarily.
The use of AJAX is not necessary in this case. A simple anchor with a target should do the trick.

###### Flask (app.py)

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
    send_file
)
from fpdf import FPDF
import io

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/pdf/create')
def create_pdf():
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.set_title('My Example PDF')
    pdf.set_author('Artist Unknown')
    pdf.set_subject('Creation of a PDF')
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
    pdf.cell(40, 10, 'Hello World')

    stream = io.BytesIO(pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1'))
    return send_file(
        stream,
        mimetype='application/pdf',
        download_name='example.pdf',
        as_attachment=False
    )
```

###### HTML (templates/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="{{ url_for('create_pdf') }}" target="_blank">Download</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Is there a way to set the name of the windows that is being opened? because for now the pdf displayed is not showing the correct file name. the tab and file name is showing as 1

Comment: The passed file name is only used to save the document. I think it could probably be possible with JavaScript. Unfortunately, I don't have enough time now to give you an example. Sorry.

Comment: @derikS4M1 I've expanded my answer slightly. If you assign a title to the pdf, this will be used as the title for the window in some browsers. I tested it in Chrome.